# change background of rating bar android

Tags: android

Hi my background of layout is white so I want to keep default colour of rating bar to blue and when selected it show yellow  colour.

```
 <RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"        
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
    />
```

please tell me how to change default colour of rating bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to change the color

```
 LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(); 
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starFullySelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starPartiallySelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starNotSelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: @apurva your code is changing color when we select the rating bar . i want default color means when page load rating bar will be of blue border or color but not white

Comment: Added the comment on diff. answer

Answer (score 0):

this solution could be of help to someone.
If you want to set the background color of Rating Bar to something consistent or make it transparent

```
ratingBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //or
ratingBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); //if you want the background color to be yellow
```